# How would I make a wave pattern onto a wall?

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry

So I want to make a wall that has a type of wave pattern, and I cannot figure out a way to do it. I read somewhere saying I could use an image as displacement but that didn't seem to work for me. [image: This is the type of texture I want]

This is the type of texture/look I want ^

If anyone can give me some pointers, that would be highly appreciated!

I did kind of manage to get a wave mesh, but whenever I tried to boolean it into the wall, even if I used the default cube, plane, etc. It just wouldn't work... It either just made the cube vanish, or it didn't actually cut into it. It just left the "shape" of the wave as if I used a knife into it... I'm fairly new so I'm sure there is something I'm missing or just am not aware of, but my god making this wall is turning out to be a major pain...thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: So I may have found a way of doing it, using the wave texture , so with how i set it up it looks 3D. However id love to know a way I could do it with actual geometry since i want you to be able to see it from the side

Answer (score 3):

in order to make this kind of texture you can play with wave and noise textures as well, here is an example:

[image: Node Setup]

Result:

[image: Result]

You can twek the settings for the texture pattern you are looking for, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Not a huge problem with poky machines, but noise is quite expensive? Maybe just one 2D noise, split out R and G from its colour output, manipulated, to use for rotation and scale of the texture-space.

Answer (score 1):

add a wave modifier and then with sculpting use grab and you get something like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't know what brush this is, but it's not the grab brush, because the grab brush is highlighted in green.

Comment: @R-800: not everybody uses the default color theme. It is the grab brush. Maybe you should think before you write.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Instagram, may help you https://www.instagram.com/p/CIfpOzTjcC4/